# Grouping buttons in lines with one button spacing two rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I group buttons with Bootstrap (specifically with Bootstrap 4), so that if I have several lines/rows of buttons, one of the buttons would occupy two rows at once? Pretty much like on a calculator or a keyboard's num pad, where Enter occupies two rows like:

```
[1] [2] [3] [E]
[  0  ] [.] [n]
```

I am pretty sure there is a simple way to do it, but I can't find it.

[upd. After seeing the previous attempt of answer I better add a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8qxy.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col-8">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">.</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

## updated